# How do you measure downstream bandwidth per user?

Tags: linux, bandwidth, inbound

In a Linux-based system (specifically, Ubuntu Server 8.04), how can you measure downstream bandwidth on a per-user basis?  Optimally, I would like a method that provides data directly instead of having to run another process and parse its output.  I have a technique for measuring per-user upstream bandwidth by setting up one iptables filter per user and checking their counters at regular intervals, but this doesn't seem to be supported for downstream connections, which I assume is because iptables checks packets before they are routed to a process.

`[edit 20080916 153434 EST]` By "per-user", I mean literal accounts on the system.  That is, any account with a real POSIX UID owning actual running processes.  So, for Ubuntu Server 8.04, measurements would include values for `root`, `www-data`, my own account, etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean "per-user basis?"  Are users connecting to you via PPP or some other mechanism and then routing traffic through you, or are people logging into the machine itself and using it locally?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any obvious way to do this as implemented, but I'd expect it would be something you could do with a custom `ip_conntrack` module.  You'd capture the uid when first creating the conntrack entry, then apply that same uid in both directions.